# Magnolia and Guice Binding Annotations

Tags: java, guice, magnolia

I'm trying to provide a `java.sql.DataSource` with an `@Provides` method and a `BindingAnnotation`. How do I tell Guice to scan a package or a class for these annotations? Do I have to setup my own Guice (servlet-) module or is that taken care of by Magnolia? As far as I understood there is a possibility to bind types with actual implementations in the Magnolia module descriptor xml, but I don't think this is practicable in this case. So far I have a provider method:

```
@Provides 
@MembershipDS 
public DataSource createDataSource() {
    // retreive the data source over JNDI and return it 
    // (calling this method manually returns an actual DataSource)
}
```

And the annotation:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MembershipDS {

}
```

But when I inject it somewhere, it is null and the provider method is not called:

```
@Inject 
@MembershipDS 
private DataSource membershipDS;
```

Note that I tried `javax.inject.Inject` and `com.google.inject.Inject` and both lead to the same result.

Comment: Not sure about magnolia. But normally that @Provides is on a Method within a Module that is passed in the creation of an Injector. The Modules themselves get 'scanned' when the Injector initialises the modules. SO my guess is you will need to put it in a module.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure these things programmatically too. Magnolia has a mechanism where you add to a configurer to your module descriptor xml file. If that class is a Guice module it will be used and can use all the Guice configuration options.

```
<components>
  <id>main</id>
  <configurer>
    <class>com.mycompany.MyConfigurer</class>
  </configurer>
  ...
</components>
```

and the class

```
public class MyConfigurer extends AbstractGuiceComponentConfigurer {
    // your Guice bindings goes here
}
```

Comment: I'm just facing the same problem and i don't understand why injection doest work. I've defined the provider and the MgnlInstantiationException keeps poping...Cant i use anotation inside a dependent module?

Comment: Would be interesting to see that exception, can you create a new question with it and a description of what you're trying to do?